# Comparing Objects (Dict/List) which has multiple childs and sub-childs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this requirement where I need to check whether my expected object contains in the actual object. I have tried some ways where it will check my expected dict/list object contains in actual dict/list object for only one level.

**Example (for dict):** `all(item in actual_value.items() for item in expected_value.items())`

**Example (for list):** `all(elem in actual_value for elem in expected_value)`

**My Requirement:** Need to check, whether the expected object contains in actual object up to n-th level. To make it clear, I'm providing the sample JSON snippets.

**Example: 1**

> Actual Object:

```
{
  "block_out_times": [
    {
      "block_out_time_id": "3ab9bd7a-bb36-41d1-80c5-48ae5133ed01",
      "employee": null,
      "room": {
        "id": "008b5252-1fe0-4cf8-88de-5fb38a2e88d5",
        "name": "Security Rooms"
      },
      "block_out_time_type": {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Repairs",
        "duration": 60
      },
      "start_time": "2020-05-29T21:00:00",
      "end_time": "2020-05-29T21:15:00",
      "start_time_in_center": "2020-05-29T14:00:00",
      "end_time_in_center": "2020-05-29T14:15:00",
      "notes": "Sample Example",
      "recurring_block_out_time": null
    }
  ],
  "error": null
}
```

> Expected Object:

```
{
  "block_out_times": [
    {
      "block_out_time_type": {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Repairs",
        "duration": 60
      }
    }
  ],
  "error": null
}
```

**Expected Response:** true (as the expected object contains in actual object)

**Example: 2**

> Actual Object:

```
[
  {
    "user_details": {
      "firstname": "john",
      "lastname": "Cobart",
      "phone":{
        "code":"91",
        "number":"8937782372"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "user_details": {
      "firstname": "robert",
      "lastname": "Anderson",
      "phone":{
        "code":"91",
        "number":"2342323423"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

> Expected Object

```
[
  {
    "user_details": {
      "phone":{
        "code":"91",
        "number":"8937782372"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "user_details": {
      "firstname": "robert",
      "lastname": "Anderson",
      "phone":{
        "code":"91",
        "number":"2342323423"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected Response:** true (as the expected object contains in the actual object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in writing a recursive algorithm. You want to check the outer most keys of the dictionary, then if it is not in there, search each of the `ActualObject[key]` objects and do the same.

(NB this is making use of a graph data structure, which is one of the most important structures in all of computer science)

### I'll let you do the coding yourself but here is some pseudo-code to get you started:

```py
# NOTE: THIS IS PSUEDOCODE - this code is just supposed to build intuition

def recursiveFunction(currentObject):
    if currentObject is a list:
        for elem in currentObject:
            if elem === expected:
                return True
    elif currentObject is a dict:
        for key in currentObject:
            if currentObject[key] === expected:
                return True

    return

# run the function
recursiveFunction(actualObject)
```

I hope that helps! LMK

Comment: Thanks for your pseudo code. It helped to build the actual code.

Comment: @KrishnaBarri amazing! glad it helped :) Good luck with the rest of the problem.